# 'module' object has no attribute 'test one'

Tags: python, unit-testing, attributeerror

Why is my test script giving me this error? Here is my code:

```
# fill_web_form_test.py

# import statements
import unittest
import fill_web_form
import sqlite3
import sys

form = 'test'
form_name = 'test_form'

if(len(sys.argv) < 2):
       raise RuntimeError('invalid number of arguments, please enter at least one arguement to be \
                        test fill_web_form.py')
for arg in sys.argv:
    if(not isinstance(arg, str)):
        raise RuntimeError('All arguments must be strings')
# these test strings will be entered by the user as the first parameter
# it will be submited to the webpage to test fill_web_form.py
data = sys.argv[1:len(sys.argv)]
print "data = " + ', '.join(data)
    
class KnownValues(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_fill_form(self):
        
        # connect to sample database
        print 'connecting to database'
        conn = sqlite3.connect('FlaskApp\FlaskApp\sample.db')
        conn.text_factory = str

        # clear database table
        print "clearing database"
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("DROP TABLE if exists test_table")
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE if not exists test_table(test_column)")
        conn.commit()
        
        # run function
        print "running fill_web_form.py"
        for data_entry in data:
            fill_web_form.fill_form("http://127.0.0.1:5000", form, form_name, data_entry)

        # get results of function from database
        print "fetching results of fill_web_form.py"
        cursor = conn.execute("SELECT * FROM test_table")
        result = cursor.fetchall()[0]
        print "Database contains strings: " + result
        expected = data

        # check for expected output
        print "checking if output is correct"
        self.assertEquals(expected, result)

# Run tests

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Here is the code for fill_web_form.py, the script that it is testing

```
# fill_web_form.py
import mechanize


def fill_form(url, form, form_name, data):
        print "opening browser"
        br = mechanize.Browser()
        print "opening url...please wait"
        br.open(url)
        print br.title()
        print "selecting form"
        br.select_form(name=form)
        print "entering string:'" + data +"' into form"
        br[form_name] = data
        print "submitting form"
        br.submit()
```

When I run `python fill_web_form_test.py "testone" "testtwo" "testthree"` in `cmd` i get this error:
[image]

My test script is supposed to take in any number of strings and send to `fill_web_form.py` which will post them to a web form I have on my system at `127.0.0.1`

But I keep gettin this error `AttributeError: module has no attribute 'testone'`I don't get it, I wasn't trying to access a module with an attribute 'testone, I was just trying to pass that string to `fill_web_form.py`

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Which line is `line 58` in your code above?

Comment: @ettanany It is the very last line in the first script `unittest.main()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget that `unittest.main` accepts command line arguments. Try:

```
>fill_web_form_test.py -h
Usage: fill_web_form_test.py [options] [test] [...]

Options:
  -h, --help       Show this message
  -v, --verbose    Verbose output
  -q, --quiet      Minimal output
  -f, --failfast   Stop on first failure
  -c, --catch      Catch control-C and display results
  -b, --buffer     Buffer stdout and stderr during test runs

Examples:
  fill_web_form_test.py                               - run default set of tests
  fill_web_form_test.py MyTestSuite                   - run suite 'MyTestSuite'
  fill_web_form_test.py MyTestCase.testSomething      - run MyTestCase.testSomething
  fill_web_form_test.py MyTestCase                    - run all 'test*' test methods
                                                        in MyTestCase
```

So your command line params `"testone" "testtwo" "testthree"` are also intepreted by `unittest.main` as the names of non-existent test cases
 in `fill_web_form_test.py`

To overcome this, specify argv like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main(argv=sys.argv[:1])
```